# Updating information like TextViews and Buttons from the main Activity class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I hope I find you well. I am new to android and I am trying to follow the tutorials on `androidhive` on developing android applications. I cam across the following tutorial on developing drawers. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/. So I was wondering if you have a button inside one of the layout files like ***fragement_home.xml*** how you go about updating it from the main activity class.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="Home View"/>


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtLabel"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
         android:background="@color/btn"
         android:text="@string/btn"
         android:textAllCaps="false"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:textSize="15dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Lets say I want to access the button btn in the fragment_home.xml and want to implement listeners on the button.

Thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: @rishad-appat I want to add a logout button

Comment: In your activity class, if you have set the content view to the same layout you want to update views of, you can use `findViewById(view id);`

Comment: Post your MainActivity code also

Comment: The simplest way to do this, is to use an Interface / Static objects

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've explain yourself better, I could try to give you better answer.

What you wanted to do, getting a Button that resides in a fragment from the activity that houses that fragment, is possible, but not in the "usual" fashion. Here's how:

First, you'll need to define a way to get that button from inside your fragment. Calling `findViewById()` in the activity won't work, because the button itself is in the fragment's layout, not in the activity's. Hence is why you're getting all that nasty `NullPointerException`s.

```
// Somewhere in your fragment..

Button mButton;

@Override
public void onCreateView(...) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_id, parent, false);

mButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
}

public Button getButton() {
    return mButton;
}
```

With that done, you can finally gain reference to it in your activity:

```
// Somewhere in your activity..

YourFragment frag = /* Get a reference to your fragment here, cast it if needed */

Button button = frag.getButton();
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener...);
```

Comment: But when I use  `(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn)` I get a null object

Comment: add this line your `onCreate` method `setContentView(R.layout.fragement_home);`

Comment: @ridsatrio. findViewById() will only work and find the id of the corresponding layout in the setContentView(R.layout.activity);

Comment: I am working with activity which contains a drawer which calls multiple fragments. If you check the tutorial you will see the code.  I am just following tutorial.  You can call it copy and paste of you want. Sorry I just lost wifi on my laptop and I an now using my phone

Comment: I take it you're trying to get that button in Activity, while the button itself is in a Fragment within that activity. Am I correct?

Comment: Check my re-revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining object of fragment in main activity .make your buton or textview or any view public in that fragment. then you can access them in main activity now you can change your view as your demand

Comment: Yes I am defining fragment in the main activity class and the fragment is returns a static view like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give you fragment access to the button. 
Quick and dirty, you can give you Activity a public field holding your button. Your fragment can then access the button by casting its Activcity field to the correct type.

If you are adding listeners be aware to remove them when fragments are destroyed.